# How to list features "in_memory"

Tags: arcpy, in-memory

I have a script that creates a number of features **"in_memory."** Once I have them in memory I need my script to create a **list** of everything **"in_memory"** - I'm not sure how to achieve this. Is anyone knowledgeable on how to achieve this result?

Below is the portion of my code that creates my features in memory.

```
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, Buffer, "in_memory" + "\\" + fc)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your workspace to in_memory, and then list feature classes there:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'

fcsInMemory = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

if you have tables in memory, and you want those too, add:

```
tblsInMemory = arcpy.ListTables()
```

If you want to guarantee that you're only grabbing the intended feature classes and that all of them are there, you could do this instead:

```
fcsOut = list()
for fc in fcs:
    fcOut = os.path.join('in_memory', fc)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, Buffer, fcOut)
    fcsOut.append(fcOut)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without necessarily having to change the workspace? Something along the lines of `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(workspace_path)`

Comment: @user32882, One would think that ESRI would be considerate enough to allow the workspace as an argument, but--as usual--they avoided the most obvious and useful option. You could use [Walk](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm), but it requires four lines of code, so you might as well change the workspace and then change it back. That said, Walk does run much faster.